# How to check who has been accessing my Linode server

Tags: ubuntu, monitoring

I've been getting "Disk IO rate warning" emails from Linode - and it looks like it's happening every 7 days. I have a few websites being hosted there and I realise that there are some APIs that I didn't secure.

What is the best way to check who (or what) has been accessing which resource on my server?

I'm using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad subject, but you could do some auditing by lining up high levels of I/O with entries in log files in /var/log.  Also, if these times are predictable, you can use iotop at the time to see what is performing I/O.

For more general use, consider installing tools like logwatch, chkrootkit, rkhunter.